# How do I get started with developing for Android without an Android phone?

Tags: android, sdk, ide

More or less as it says on the tin.

Before I even contemplate downloading the SDK, I was wondering if there was any way of testing Android apps that I'd write without an Android phone available to me? I'm unsure as to whether or not the tools that come with the SDK come with an emulator like VS does for Windows Mobile.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

**Edit** I don't suppose there's anything that'll let me write widgets on/for an emulated version of the interface HTC use on the Hero/G2 either is there? Not that it would matter that much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an emulator available as part of the SDK.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: ah I wasn't 100% sure or not. Maybe I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: am I also able to develop test apps for Android with the SDK without having to pay to be on the Marketplace (it's something I'd like to do in the future but at this very moment, I just want to get to grips with it.)

Answer (score 4):

I'd add that the emulator is really quite comprehensive.  Things like camera previews don't actually display camera data, but they put block animations in their place.  All in all it's one of the best mobile emulators I've seen to date.  Probably better even than *gasp* the iPhone simulator.

Comment: is Android particularly easy to develop for?

Comment: @Liam Gulliver - Depends on your background, but it has a gentler learning curve than the iPhone. iPhone you need to get a handle on some memory management stuff while with Android it's GC'd.

Comment: Mines all VB.NET and a smidgen of C#.

Comment: The C# will come in handy as you move to Java (I think)  Really, you need to get up to speed on Java before you can dive into Android.  (You can always buy my *cough*ebook*cough* Android Essentials on APress.  I got a lot of out O'Reilly's Head First Java book.  Those stupid catchy phrases and diagrams...

Answer (score 4):

As said above there's an emulator available,however with larger apps it gets fairly tedious to use the emulator.Its fine for learning the ins and outs but id suggest investing in an android phone once you've got a good grasp of the sdk,it really does make a difference!.

Comment: I'm contemplating if I do push ahead with it, investing in the G1 Google sell for $399.

But we'll see how we progress.

Comment: You really can get a feel for it with the emulator.  I'd suggest doing most of your work with that first before dropping 400$ on a device you may not like developing for.

Comment: If you only want it to test your software, I'm sure you can a G1 off of Ebay for half that.